# Jquery - Add a dynamic class to another DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery

OK, perhaps the title doesnt best explain what im trying to achive but if I can explain better hopefully someone can help me out:

Im using the following code to select the text held within `<a>` and add it as the class of that element:

```
$(".nav a").each(function () {
  var self = $(this);
  self.addClass(self.text());
});
```

So for instance:

```
<a class="nav" href="page1.html">Google</a>
<a class="nav" href="page2.html">Yahoo</a>
<a class="nav" href="page3.html">Bing</a>
```

Becomes:

```
<a class="nav Google" href="page1.html">Google</a>
<a class="nav Yahoo" href="page2.html">Yahoo</a>    
<a class="nav Bing" href="page3.html">Bing</a>
```

Im using another bit of code to find out which page the user is currently on, either Google, Yahoo or Bing, and I then allocate another class of 'Selected'

e.g If i was on the Google page the `<a>` class becomes:

```
<a class="nav Google selected" href="page1.html">Google</a>
```

I would like to extend this a little further and can probably explain best via an example:

```
<a class="nav Google selected" href="page1.html">Google</a>
<a class="nav Yahoo" href="page2.html">Yahoo</a>    
<a class="nav Bing" href="page3.html">Bing</a>

<div class="container Google">

Lots of content

</div>
```

So as above, when 'Google' has the class 'selected' add that to `<div class="container">`, and the same for when the other links are clicked.

So in other words which ever `<a>` holds 'selected' add the previous class to `<div class="container">`

I know there are many ways to do this in far less 'hacky' ways but I have no other choice but to do it this way as I cannot edit the source of the page in anyway so it has to be a browser based solution rather than server side.

Comment: When you click a different link, do you want to remove the "Google" class and add the "Yahoo" class?  Or is it not an issue because the page will reload and any dynamically added classes will be cleared?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.nav').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass($(this).text());  // I believe you already do this.
    $('.conatiner').addClass($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the class to the container like this:

```
$('.conatiner').addClass($('a.selected').text());
```